# why react-router-dom v6 always navigate to /not-found only in production mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, create-react-app

while my router works quite well in development mode, always navigate to /* and not-found path in production mode.

here is the code

```
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <AuthGuard component={<Home />} />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/groups"
                element={
                  <AuthGuard
                    backgroundColor='darkRed'
                    component={<Groups />}
                  />
                }
              >
                <Route
                  path=":groupId"
                  element={<Groups />}
                />
              </Route>
              <Route
                path="/join-group/:groupCode"
                element={<JoinGroup />}
              />
              <Route
                path="/matches"
                element={
                  <AuthGuard
                    component={<Matches />}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/see-more"
                element={
                  <AuthGuard component={<SeeMore/>} />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/remote-login"
                element={<RemoteLogin />}
              />
              <Route
                path="/not-found"
                element={<NotFound />}
              />
              <Route
                path="*"
                element={<Navigate to="/not-found"/>}
              />
            </Routes>
```

when run serve the project's build on my server, no path is recognized and navigate to /not-found

thanks in advence

Comment: Where are you deploying the app and how is the server serving it?

Comment: it serves on nginx, it would be a great help if you could give more information. @DrewReese

Comment: Take a look at the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get an idea what may need to be configured for the server/app wherever the app is deployed to.